# Winexe installation in Linux

Tags: samba, winexe

I am trying to compile and build winexe. I have downloaded the samba source and ran the following command to compile the winexe.

```
./waf configure --samba-dir=../../samba --samba-inc-dirs=../../samba/ --samba-lib-dirs=../../samba/
```

I am getting the following error. Please suggest me to resolve the error.

```
[3326/3810] Compiling default/source/smb_static/smb_static.objlist.empty.c
Waf: Leaving directory `/root/samba/bin'
Build failed: could not find 'source/smb_static/smb_static.objlist.empty.c' for
        {task: cc smb_static.objlist.empty.c -> smb_static.objlist.empty_2.o}
Checking for library smb_static                     : not found
Build of static winexe                              : disabled
Cannot continue! Please either install Samba shared libraries and re-run waf, or download the Samba source code and re-run waf with the "--samba-dir" option.
(complete log in /root/winexe/source/build/config.log)
```

Comment: Well, the error is pretty self explaining, isn't it? You do not have the required libraries installed.

Comment: Yes.. But I tried to install the libraries, but not able to find one.

Comment: There is a difference between libraries required to build something and the thing you want to build itself. If you really want to link against not installed libraries, maybe because they are located inside your build folder, then you have to adjust the paths to allow compiler and linker to find them.

Answer (score 0):

execfile is deprecated,

edit the file "smb_static/wscript",

remove the line with execfile and use exec(open("wscript").read()) instead